# Sandboxed JavaScript runtime engine (Chrome/Firefox/Opera/whatever)

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a script written in JS. And I want to run it in a sandboxed mode, as if it were some browser, allowing DOM manipulation and network, but without any persistence (cache, cookies, local storage, etc.) and with a fixed execution duration (let us say 60 seconds).

I want to capture DOM state with a series of samples, then to analyze the contents.

API could be anything than can be accessed from Java.

Here is an example, what I would like to achieve:

```
val myScript = "document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('foo'))"
Chrome.SandboxedWindow().execute(myScript, duration = 60, onDomDhanged = {
    snapshots.add(takeSnapsot()) // whatever
})
...
println(snapshots[0].domContents.toString())
```

Is there any ready-made solution, or where can I start from?

Comment: Might a so called "Headless Browser" be the tool set you want to use? [Here](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) you can find a collection of a lot of such tools.

Comment: Probably yes, thank you

Comment: I added this as an answer including an example of such a tool! It looks very similar to the code snippet you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overall

Your needs fit the description of a headless browser. One of those descriptions can be found [here](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

> A web browser without a graphical user interface, controlled programmatically. Used for automation, testing, and other purposes. - [*Source*](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers#a-list-of-almost-all-headless-web-browsers-in-existence)

Also there is a list with lots of such browsers. In your case [jBrowserDriver](https://github.com/machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver) might be the right choice. But the list is huge and there are alternatives as well.

## jBrowserDriver

The following shows an example provided [here](https://github.com/machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver#usage). You should pack your script within a simple .html file which can be loaded using `driver.get();` afterwards. You can as well simply set up a local server for this. The line `println(snapshots[0].domContents.toString())` of yours already looks similar to a line in the example which does `System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());`.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Timezone;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Settings;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // You can optionally pass a Settings object here,
    // constructed using Settings.Builder
    JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().
      timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK).build());

    // This will block for the page load and any
    // associated AJAX requests
    driver.get("http://example.com");

    // You can get status code unlike other Selenium drivers.
    // It blocks for AJAX requests and page loads after clicks 
    // and keyboard events.
    System.out.println(driver.getStatusCode());

    // Returns the page source in its current state, including
    // any DOM updates that occurred after page load
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

    // Close the browser. Allows this thread to terminate.
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```